# Glossary - types of riders

Tags: road-bike, racing, terminology

I'd like to create a terminology index for the types or *categories* of riders, similar to this [question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/). By types of riders I mean the categories that pro racers are often identified as being part of or self identify as, i.e. `sprinter, climber, time trailist ...`

**Rules**

Answers should include:

- One *type* of rider per answer - i.e. the answer title is "*Sprinter*"
- A description of the the archetype of the rider
- An example of a pro who embodies the archetype
- A picture of the aforementioned pro that shows body type

Comment: Trails, trials and time trials are usually considered different categories. But what is time trail?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not really a question that suits the SE format. If you rephrase this to ask what the terms are, rather create them then the answers should be able to provide a reference.

Comment: Why wouldn't those just go in the glossary with everything else?

Comment: @mattnz I don't know all the types of riders, just some of the more common ones I hear. I would expect others who know a type to answer with it. I want a list of all the types but with detailed info, pics, etc. Do you suggest I rephrase to ask for all the types, plus the info I originally asked for, as a single answer?

Comment: @Mσᶎ by glossary do you mean the question I linked to? If so, I didn't think parts and rider types belonged in the same list. However, having a second look, the question does say "cycling concepts" so I could see that fitting. But I doubt it would attract anyone to list rider types.

Comment: @ebrohman you mean even less so than this question? And yes, it continues to disappoint me that we have a perfectly good word for "terminology index" but don't use it.

Comment: @Mσᶎ  you're right, glossary is better word. However, I don't see why you think the question wouldn't attract anyone to answer with a known rider type, I mean less so than the other glossary question which is predominantly parts related. I thought it was asked in a pretty straightforward manner. I'd like to get some real answers so if you have any suggestions to improve the question I'm all ears and would appreciate feedback.

Answer (score 2):

### **Sprinter**

A sprinter is a type of rider who is known for explosive power and acceleration.  They often have a large build, usually with massive quads and strong upper bodies.

Since they are relatively heavier than other riders their speed advantage is often limited to flatter sections and they can and are often dropped in hilly terrain.

Sprinters are know for drafting in the slipstream of teammates (usually the domestiques) who are sheltering them, before launching into a sprint in the final meters of a race.

Some sprinters are stronger in hillier terrain and cobblestones, and are sometimes categorized to be *Puncheurs*.  They often excel in the classics races.

**Mark Cavendish**

- considered one of the best contemporary sprinters, he has 43 stage wins in Grand Tours, 25 of which were bunch sprints in the TdF going head to head with the best sprinters in the world.

[image]

Comment: +1 for mentioning Cav. Not only an ace sprinter but also someone who knows how to rock a proper casquette.

Answer (score -2):

A road rider sprinter .who is known for explosive power and acceleration.sprinter are known for drafting. this often excel in the classic races. sprinter is a professional bicycle.

Comment: Please expand your answer to fit the required outline.  You need to name example professional riders who fit this type, and add a photo clearly showing the posture and body type.